# Ruby initialize method when to use parenthesis

Tags: ruby, initialization

I'm trying to understand the initialize method but am having trouble with the use of parenthesis. In the following examples, [from here](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/objinitialization.html), they don't use "apple" and "ripe" in parenthesis, yet in the 2nd example they only use (k). How do we know in what instances to use parenthesis or not?

```
class Fruit
    def initialize
        @kind = "apple"
        @condition = "ripe"
    end
end

class Fruit
   def initialize( k )
     @kind = k
     @condition = "ripe"
   end
end
```

Comment: `"apple"` and `"ripe"` are string literals, whereas `k` is a parameter. The parentheses are optional where no parameters are defined.

Comment: If you'd like to avoid downvotes, don't ask questions that are answered in the first few chapters of any halfway-decent turorial.

Comment: @johrsharpe you are working with a flawed assumption, that I didn't research the question. I did, I didn't find an answer to my question, or I didn't understand the answers, which brought me here. The amazing thing is that, when people can downvote with complete anonymity they do so wantonly, but when they get pushback, they resort to arrogance and flawed assumptions.

Comment: If my assumption was inaccurate, that is because your question shows no evidence of any research. It doesn't mention what you've searched for, what you've, already read what you've learned or what you'd still like to know in specific terms. That's your fault, not mine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - another flawed assumption. You assume that listing a laundry list of failed attempts of finding an answer prevents programmers like you from downvoting. It doesn't. SOers like you block posts that are "opinion based" yet you wantonly downvote based on your opinion and god forbid if anyone objects. Again, contributing to a welcome environment for people who want to learn. You get off by punishing, and get irate when challenged when you simply could have ignored posts like mine and go help someone. Instead you punish, simply because you can.

Comment: Please read the [ask] and the downvote tooltip. If you've got a problem with that, take it up on Meta. I won't respond further here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, parentheses are used to enclose the argument list of the `initialize` method.

```
def initialize
    @kind = "apple"
    @condition = "ripe"
end
```

takes no parameters. `"apple"` and `"ripe"` are string literals. You could use parentheses if you wanted to but they're omitted by convention. The code is equivalent to:

```
def initialize() #no parameters
    @kind = "apple"
    @condition = "ripe"
end
```

but the parentheses enclosing the empty parameter list are just dropped for brevity.

In your second example:

```
def initialize( k )
    @kind = k
    @condition = "ripe"
end
```

`@kind` is initialized to the value of the parameter `k`.

The parameterless `initialize` method will be used when you call `Fruit.new`. To use the one from the second example, you'd need to provide a value for the parameter `k` when creating the object, `Fruit.new("apple")`

Comment: this helps me understand a lot of what's going on. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. If you need, for example lets say, set some default values to some variables in the initializer method of a class, you don't need to use parenthesis at all, just setting the values to your variables into the method will be enough. That's exactly what they do in:

```
def initialize
|     @kind = "apple"
|     @condition = "ripe"
|   end
```

For instance, if you need to set a custom value to one or more of your variables, you may need to use parenthesis to pass your custom values as parameters in your object creation call, as the do in (You may use as many variables into parenthesis as custom values you want send):

```
def initialize( k )
|     @kind = k
|     @condition = "ripe"
|   end
```

So, you create the object like:

```
Fruit.new your_custom_value_or_object
```

You can set a default value to your parameters in your initializer method parenthesis in case you don't pass any parameter, which is exactly what they do in:

```
def initialize( k="apple" )
|     @kind = k
|     @condition = "ripe"
|   end
```

If you dont pass any parameter when you create the object, then @kind will be set to "apple".